# Invalidate Android Preferences State Upon App Version Update

Tags: android, google-play, version, state, preferences

Need to wipe out app's preferences upon update to next version.

I'm storing a bunch of keys and a few small serialized objects in preferences, object model for which changed and would raise an exception if new version of the app is opened against old preferences.

How would I go about enforcing this in the new version, so that when users update from GooglePlay previous preferences would be wiped out?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle this manually by writing some special key to your prefs. You can create a customized subclass of `Application` and handle this in its `onCreate` method, for example something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int curVersionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
        if(prefs.getInteger(VERSION_KEY, -1) != curVersionCode) {             
           // new app version detected, proceed as needed
           doStuff();
           // do not forget to update
           prefs.edit()
             .putInteger(VERSION_KEY, curVersionCode)
             .apply();
        }
    }
}
```

In Android manifest:

> ```
> <application android:name=".MyApplication">
> ...
> ```

By utilizing `Application.onCreate()` call you can be sure that this check will be performed before any activity is launched - it is called only once on app start.

Comment: Thank you for this. Storing version in prefs is a good idea. How would I go about deleting entire preference state? I'm completely fine wiping out all of user's preferences entirely. Would like to avoid deleting 1 by 1..

Comment: I guess you can utilize a support for different preference files, i.e. use context.getSharedPreferences(NAME1, 0) instead of default prefs I depicted above. You can have separate versions store state in separate files and then do prefs.edit().clear().apply() to wipe a particular one as needed. Also you can store your version number in separate prefs file so that this information would survive all wipes.

Comment: Ah, and if you just need to wipe out all pref keys, just do prefs.edit().clear().apply(). At first I thought that you'd like to store prefs for each version separately :) In any case, be sure to store you versioning info in other prefs file as I said in prev comment